money transfer on stripe subscription mode in nodejs
How can I transfer a $20 payment to a connected account on Stripe while creating a subscription using Stripe Checkout?"
I want to create a subscription plan where payments are transferred to a connected account.
How can achieve this?

You can follow this guide https://docs.stripe.com/connect/creating-a-payments-page?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted#subscriptions This will create Subscriptions with Direct Charges. If you want Destination charges (which is seems you do), you would replace the stripe-account header with subscription_data.transfer_data.destination https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-transfer_data
